# Why recipients in Laravel Mail queue are stacking up?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am trying to send emails to users in bulk. I set up queue and supervisor according to laravel documentation but recipients in Mail are stacking up and I really don't know what's wrong because everything looks fine in the code. Here is how I am queuing Mails.

```
$message = (new \App\Mail\EmailUpdate(request('subject'),request('message')))->onQueue('emailsDefault');
foreach($users as $user){
    \Mail::to($user)->queue($message);
}
```

I thought there must be some issue selecting segment of users from database. But I tried with `php artisan tinker` and it shows perfect results. Here is how I am getting collection of users from the database.

```
$users = User::join('user_metas','users.id','=','user_metas.user_id')
             ->where('meta_key','plan')
             ->where('meta_value','free')
             ->select('users.id')
             ->get();
```

In recipients part of the Emails, I can see an increment in the number of recipients. Here is how it looks like in mailtrap.io.

[image: Check the 'to' part of the emails]

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know what I am missing here. Here is my **EmailUpdate Mailable**.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EmailUpdate extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject;
    public $update;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($subject,$update)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->update = $update;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.emailUpdate')
                    ->subject($this->subject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you reset $users to NULL at the end of the loop? If not, that is your problem.

Comment: But that loop gets executed only once. More than that, I am using `foreach` loop which means each email is queued individually, right?

Comment: How are we supposed to know the loop only runs once, you have barely done a MCVE

Comment: Cool! You know what. Maybe you should read the post again. I am just trying to queue emails for group of users. You can't really understand the question. right? It's better to find solution myself. It always works.

Comment: I showed you how I am getting users collection. I showed you how I am trying to queue emails. I also showed you the results I am getting. How is this not a freaking MCVE! Really bro, If you can't understand the question, you can just ignore it.

Comment: Whenever you work with queues, make sure to restart the worker after each change in the code. I've gone nearly crazy looking for a bug when in fact the worker was running some old code

Comment: @Borjante, Yes, It always happens. But I have already tried restarting the worker. It's giving me the same results.

Comment: Then Andreas might be rigth. This code looks OK to me, maybe you are missing something else

Comment: Thanks @ andreas and @ Borjante for help. I am looking into something else because the code looks perfect to me too! :v

Answer (score 1):

I updated the following code:

```
$message = (new \App\Mail\EmailUpdate(request('subject'),request('message')))->onQueue('emailsDefault');
foreach($users as $user){
    \Mail::to($user)->queue($message);
}
```

to the following code:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $message = (new \App\Mail\EmailUpdate(request('subject'),request('message')))->onQueue('emailsDefault');
    \Mail::to($user)->queue($message);
}
```

And it is working! I don't know why this is happening because we are not defining users in the `$message` instance. If anyone knows the reason behind why this happens the way this happens, I am very curious to know.

Comment: Show your EmailUpdate mailable in the question please

Comment: Sure! Just a minute,.

Comment: Please check. I have updated question with mailable.

Comment: Okay, I got it! I think the issue with the previous code was, I was sending the same message to multiple users and somehow Laravel kept embedding users to the recipients of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a small refactor of the code.

```
$users = User::join('user_metas','users.id','=','user_metas.user_id')
             ->where('meta_key','plan')
             ->where('meta_value','free')
             ->select('users.id')
             ->get();

$email = new \App\Mail\EmailUpdate(request('subject'),request('message')));
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        Mail::queue(email);
    }
```

It's because I'm not sure about your:
Mail::to()->queue();

Anyway last check, is there any job failing in the failed_jobs table?

Comment: Actually, the code you wrote isn't sending emails at all. It's obvious because you are not defining user while sending Email. No jobs in failed_jobs.

Comment: Sorry sir, still early in the morning. Please update your question with your EmailUpdate mailable

Comment: Solved the issue. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could set empty the "to" property of the mailable object

```
$message = (new \App\Mail\EmailUpdate(request('subject'),request('message')))->onQueue('emailsDefault');
foreach($users as $user){
    $message->to = [];
    \Mail::to($user)->queue($message);
}
```

Or Just make a new instance for each iteration as you answered yourself

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $message = (new \App\Mail\EmailUpdate(request('subject'),request('message')))->onQueue('emailsDefault');
    \Mail::to($user)->queue($message);
}
```

Why? Idk, apparently each Mail::to() iteration are stacking up the addresses in the to property instead of set a new one.

Enjoy :)